# Use Jasmine to test a service with uibModal and lodash as dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-ui-bootstrap, lodash

This is my first time using Jasmine, and I have tested my first Factory without problems.

But now, I want to test this Service:

```
angular.module('Questions', [])
.service('QuestionsService', function($uibModal, $log, _) { 
  ... 
}
```

$uibModal is from UI Bootstrap (see [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)) and _ is Lodash.

My Jasmine test so far is:

```
describe('Service: QuestionsService', function() {

    var QuestionsService;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_QuestionsService_) {
      QuestionsService = _QuestionsService_;
    }));

    ...
}
```

And when I try it (grunt test), I get the following error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- QuestionsService

And at some point I also had:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: _Provider <- _ <- QuestionsService

If it can help, my Karma conf is:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  'use strict';
  config.set({
    autoWatch: true,
    basePath: '../',

    frameworks: [
      "jasmine"
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      // bower:js
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'bower_components/lodash/lodash.js',
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      // endbower
      "app/scripts/**/*.js",
      "test/mock/**/*.js",
      "test/spec/**/*.js",
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    port: 8080,
    browsers: [
      "PhantomJS"
    ],
    plugins: [
      "karma-phantomjs-launcher",
      "karma-jasmine"
    ],
    singleRun: false,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
  });
};
```

Comment: In your karma configuration file, where you defined what files to include,  explicitly define your application initialization (`app.js`) after the bower dependencies, but before the rest of your files.  So it would go right before `"app/scripts/**/*.js"`.  It is possible that you could have written new files that karma adds before you application's boot file.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to add my "app/scripts/app.js" before "app/scripts/**/*.js", but the problem remained.

Comment: And your `app.js` includes the Lodash and UI-Bootstrap? `angular.module('app', ['underscore', 'ui.bootstrap']);`

Comment: Yes :( ...     
What is strange is that I have no injection problem for these 2 dependencies in the application. 
I only have the problem when I launch the Jasmine tests ... 
Do you think there is an other place where I should require it for Jasmine ?

Comment: Ok, the problem was indeed linked with the app module.
I included the right dependencies for the app. However, in my test code, I only included the module I wanted to test : 

    beforeEach(module('Questions'));

And I forgot to include my application module :

    beforeEach(module('boardgameApp'));

Thank you.

Comment: Nice catch.  I can't believe someone else (like me) never saw it.  I think the hardest part of unit testing is the actual setup lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app's module was not included in the test. The refactored test for the `QuestionService` would be:

```
describe('Service: QuestionsService', function() {

    var QuestionsService;

    // The module needs to be included in the test.
    beforeEach(module('boardgameApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_QuestionsService_) {
      QuestionsService = _QuestionsService_;
    }));

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case others find this.  To solve the error when testing a directive's controller, I mocked the $uibModal service, conceptually like this:

```
describe('Service: QuestionsService', function() {

    var controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        controller = $controller('controllerName', {
            $uibModal : {}
        });
    }));

    ...
}
```

$uibModal may need to be more than just an empty object if you are writing tests against controller functions that interact with it.